# Верно ли расставлены запятые? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение

Ес­ли от Ли­са я знаю, че­го мож­но ожи­дать и уже об­ща­лась с ним, то вот что ждать от Змея, я по­нятия не имею.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Указанные запятые стоят верно, но (если без оговорок принять исходное предложение) нужна еще одна после *"ожидать"*, чтобы закрыть придаточное предложение *"че­го мож­но ожи­дать"* в составе сложного.

Логически предложение следует перестроить:

*Ес­ли с Ли­сом я уже общалась и знаю, че­го мож­но ожи­дать от него, то вот что ждать от Змея, я по­нятия не имею.*

Еще смущают разные падежи в сочетаниях *"чего ожидать"* и *"что ждать"*. Я бы использовал в обоих случаях *"чего ожидать"* или *"чего ждать"*.

Вместо последней запятой можно поставить тире:

*Ес­ли с Ли­сом я уже общалась и знаю, че­го мож­но ожи­дать от него, то вот чего ожидать от Змея — я по­нятия не имею.*